# Computing $\int_0^1 \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n} \; dx$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

I am trying to compute $\int_0^1 \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}  \; dx$. Using an online calculator, I found the answer to be $\frac{(n+1)^{1-n}}{(n-1)} - \frac{n}{n-1}$. When I tried to verify this, I got:

> $$\int_0^1 \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}  \; dx= n^n\int_0^1(n+x)^{-n}\; dx = \frac{n^n}{1-n} \cdot \left[(n+x)^{1-n}\right|_{x=0}^1 = \frac{n^n}{(1+n)^{n-1}(1-n)}-\frac{n}{1-n}$$

This is not the same as the answer I for from the online calculator. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Hint: Substitute $u=1+x/n$.

Comment: What online calculator did you use?

Comment: I was using Wolfram Alpha

Comment: Your answer is correct. See [Wolframalpha](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4033419/computing-int-01-left1-fracxn-right-n-dx). Maybe you made an error while using the calculator.

Comment: @LightYagami I think that's what happened most likely.

Comment: ...or WA just showed one of its infamous bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^1\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{-n}dx=n\int_0^1\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{-n}\,d\left(1+\frac xn\right)=\left.n\frac{\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{-n+1}}{-n+1}\right|_0^1=$$

$$=\frac n{1-n}\left[\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{-n+1}-1\right]=\frac n{1-n}\left[\frac{n^{n-1}}{(1+n)^{n-1}}-1\right]$$

the above is true for $\;n\neq1\;$, and in this last case we'd get

$$\int_0^1\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{-1}dx=n\int_0^1\frac{dx}{n+x}=n\log|x+n|_0^1=n\log\frac{n+1}n$$

Comment: Out of curiosity, if the task were to compute $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1 \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n} \; dx$, then would it matter what happens at $n=1$?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson No, then it wouldn't as we can choose $\;n\ge7\;$ , say...or any other number instead $\;7\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $n\ne 1$, your calculation is correct.

---

Consider the case when $n=2$.

Your calculation gives $2-\frac43=\frac23$ but the other one gives $\frac13-2<0$, which cannot be right since the integrand is nonnegative.

---

[image]

[image]